# Exp.downloadTemplateApp is not a function

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an issue when create init new React Native Project

I got error `(_xdl || _load_xdl(...)).Exp.downloadTemplateApp is not a function`
I dont know what is that, because im new in React Native.

My version :

```
node : v8.10.0
npm : 3.5.2
yarn : 1.17.3
expo : 2.4.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing the following steps;

```
npm uninstall -g expo-cli

npm install -g expo-cli
```

that was working for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case on Ubuntu 20.04 `exp` library doesn't work properly, and I got the same error, so try to install `expo-cli` and hit `expo init` (not `exp init`), it should make the job done